# Как программно сделать перенос строки в word

Tags: java, ms-word

Собираю строку

```
String text = data.get(15) + "тут_enter" + data.get(1);
```

и записываю её в вордовский документ.
Так и не нашел, какой символ вставить вместо "тут_enter" что бы была запись в 2 строки?
Я знаю, что можно сделать по другому, но интересует есть ли какой ни будь символ/код для переноса?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте \n вместо "тут_enter".

```
String text = data.get(15) + "\n" + data.get(1);
```

Comment: Нет, ни \n, ни ^p не помогает(

Comment: А что выводит в word?

Comment: Эти же символы именно так как и написаны \n - ^p